# PHP: Why does my strip_tags('<', '<br>') return empty string?

Tags: php

I have a function that is used to strip unwanted HTML tag.
e.g

```
function getValidStrings($inputStr, $allowedTag) {
   return trim(strip_tags($inputStr, $allowedTag));
} // End function

// Here I am calling this function which is defined in an included php Class file
$formatter = new $StringTextFormatter;

$validString = $formatter->getValidStrings('<', '<br>');
// The $validString has empty string "" ... Why ?
```

When I pass '<' character to strip_tags, it returns empty. 
However, strip_tags does give correct char if I pass in '>'.

**I need to be able to return '<' from above call. 
Any idea what the solution could be?**

Comment: The second parameter is allowed tags, `<` is not a tag.  What are you tring to do?

Comment: _**Warning**
Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected._ http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Correct. But if a input string has "<" character,  shouldn't strip_tags allow it to process? And return that same char ? Because it is just a char and not a complete tag.

Comment: @Clive Thanks. But it does take a  ">" and return it back. Yes this is confusing!

Comment: No tag starts with a `>` so that makes sense, yes. Sort of. I can see why you asked.

Comment: Looks like my solution approach is to treat a single char string as a special case as a work around for this solution,  e.g. if (strcmp(inputStr, '<') === 0) { // then do not call strip_tag}

Comment: I am finalizing on writing my own custom function for string processing the way I wanted using regex. Probably best approach for my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're in a html context. If an html parser encounters `<`, that's an opening tag. If `<` doesn't have that meaning, then you *need* to replace it with its equivalent html entity: `&lt;`

Answer (score 2):

As Federkun said, it's seeing `<` as the start of a tag. You passed in broken HTML and it did its best to give you what you want: a string without (most)HTML. As Clive noted, they warned you about this in the manual

> Because strip_tags() does not actually validate the HTML, **partial or broken tags can result in the removal of more text/data than expected.**

If you pass anything after that bad `<` it gets stripped as well. it's got to be something even remotely close to HTML for it to work properly

```
echo strip_tags('<bad HTML string here<br>'); // empty string
echo strip_tags('<bad HTML<br> Hello!'); // Also empty
echo strip_tags('<bad HTML> Hello!'); // Hello!
```